# Random parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this may be a very basic question, sorry if it is but in javascript/jquery i sometimes come into contact with a function having a random parameter that doesn't seem to serve an obvious purpose, such as this one below used on the jquery website.

```
    $("div").mousemove(function(e){  
      var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";  
      var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";  
      $("span:first").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);  
      $("span:last").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);  
    });
```

Here the function has a parameter of e, i don't get why though i know if it didn't have an e it could also work because that's how i tend to use javascript. Why would a programmer do this?

Comment: `e` is the event object. It's being used in this code. Why do you think it's random or unnecessary?

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be downvoted?

Comment: @tenfour Chill man, Chad is sorry to have asked a very basic question, no need to downvote.

Comment: My comment is asking for clarification; why do you think I need to "chill?" This question 1) shows no research effort (http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/), 2) is unclear (hence the clarifications), 3) is not likely to be helpful to future SO users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `e` represents the event object. In the example given, the user needs the event object so that he/she can access the location of the cursor on the screen when the mousemove event is fired, using the `pageX` and `pageY` properties of the event (e) object.

Comment: Could any letter or no letter be subsituted for the e?

Comment: Yes, JS doesn't care what and if you name it. @Chad

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever you like, but it is good practice to use e, evt, or event to make the code clear to understant. But you must use some letter or else you will not be able to access the properties of the event, if you don't need the properties then you don't need the argument.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't random, it is always there. But if you don't want to use it, you can just leave it away. That parameter (e in this case) is  the event. They use it to get the coordinates of the mousemove, these are stored in the event object and passed to the function. The event is not the only parameter that is passed to this function, as you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/), although the others are quite rare.